# Post in apex oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to write post data to a table, but the data is in an array. I wrote the code, but for some reason it doesn't work, it can help to find the error.it does not produce errors, it writes empty columns!

```html
    sCount := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'quantitative_index' , p_values => tv); 
    IF sCount > 0 THEN 
      FOR i in 1 .. sCount LOOP 
        q_id   := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'quantitative_indexs['|| i ||'].id', p_values => tv); 
        q_name := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'quantitative_indexs['|| i ||'].name', p_values => tv); 
        q_guid := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'quantitative_indexs['|| i ||'].guid', p_values => tv); 
        select count(*) into v_det_vol from DETAILS_VOLUME where ID  = q_id and NAME = q_name; 
        if v_det_vol = 0 then 
          INSERT INTO DETAILS_VOLUME (ID, NAME, guid)  
            VALUES (q_id, q_name ,q_guid); 
          commit;           
        end if; 
      END LOOP; 
    END IF;
```

here's the  json

```html
{

  "quantitative_index": [
    {
      "id": 12121,
      "name": "Менеджер",
    "guid": "100"
    },
  {
      "id": 12122,
      "name": "Менеджер1",
    "guid": "100"
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
sCount := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'quantitative_index' , p_values => tv); 
    IF sCount > 0 THEN 
      FOR i in 1 .. sCount LOOP 
        q_id   := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'quantitative_indexs['|| i ||'].id', p_values => tv); 
        q_name := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'quantitative_indexs['|| i ||'].name', p_values => tv); 
        q_guid := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'quantitative_indexs['|| i ||'].guid', p_values => tv); 
        select count(*) into v_det_vol from DETAILS_VOLUME where ID  = q_id and NAME = q_name; 
        if v_det_vol = 0 then 
          INSERT INTO DETAILS_VOLUME (ID, NAME, guid)  
            VALUES (1, '1' ,'1'); 
          commit;           
        end if; 
      END LOOP; 
    END IF;
```

And if so, it records!

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error message? Can't you parse the Json?

Comment: @Rene it does not produce errors, it writes empty columns

Comment: @Rene I supplemented my question with an example of where the recording takes place

Comment: Please provide a complete piece of code to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: I don't know this topic, but in json you have `index` and in your code it's `indexs`. Maybe typo?

Comment: @PonderStibbons "quantitative_index" is simply the name of the array

Comment: yes this is my syntax error, thanks @PonderStibbons

Answer (score 0):

Your code is referencing `quantitative_indexs` but the name of the property is `quantitative_index` No 's' on the end.

Also, don't commit in a loop, do it outside of the loop or just let APEX do it for you.